# Chrome DevTools extension script not loaded when DevTools already opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a [Chrome DevTools extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools). So, I have `devtools_page` field in the manifest:

```
{
  "name": ...
  "version": ...,
  "minimum_chrome_version": ...,
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  ...
}
```

In `devtools.html` file, I am using `script.js` script.

When the extension is loaded, if Chrome DevTools gets opened, `script.js` gets executed. However, if Devtools is already opened before the extension loads, `script.js` doesn't get executed when the extension loads. It doesn't even get executed if I refresh the page.

In Firefox, `script.js` file gets executed whether the DevTools is opened before or after loading the extension.

My questions are:

- Am I missing something?
- If I am not missing anything, is this the desired behavior in Chrome, or it might be a bug?

Comment: You can ask to change the behavior on https://crbug.com.